# Why Rollup doesn't generate "import css" line to the bundled file?

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

does anyone know why Rollup doesn't generate `import css` line to the output `js` file?
Here is my rollup config:

```js
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    file: "dist/index.js",
    format: "es"
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      typescript: require("typescript")
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: true,
      extensions: [".less"],
      use: [["less", { javascriptEnabled: true }]]
    })
  ]
};
```

src/index.ts:

```
import "./index.less";
```

What I expected result is as following:

```
`require("./index.css");`
```

But the bundled result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
extract: true
```

This option moves the css to a seperate .css file instead of including it in the .js file.

Comment: what do you mean by put in the .js file ?