# How to setup PostCSS nesting in Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, postcss

This is what I’ve tried so far:

1. Installed via `npm install postcss-nesting --save-dev`
2. Setup vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import postcssNesting from 'postcss-nesting';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        postcssNesting
    ],
  
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    }
});
```

But it’s not working. What’s the right way to setup PostCSS so that I can use CSS nesting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to get it work like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import postcssNesting from 'postcss-nesting';

export default defineConfig({
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                postcssNesting
            ],
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Just create a file on the root of your project called `postcss.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-nesting': { /* plugin options */ },
  },
}
```

---

Vite uses [postcss-load-config](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-load-config) which means that it can pick up the postcss config file (file name can be one of the many formats supported by this package e.g. `postcss.config.js`, `.postcssrc`, `.postcssrc.js` etc).

---

If you want nesting with PostCSS just like you do it in SASS, I suggest you use [postcss-nested](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested).

If you want to use it together with TailwindCSS, you don't have to install it since it's included directly in the `tailwindcss` package itself:

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

[TailwindDocs: Nesting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting)

Comment: Somewhat related: Is there a way to then configure vite to not extract the CSS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858580/why-rollup-doesnt-generate-import-css-line-to-the-bundled-file